# how clear PHP startup warnings?

Tags: php

I have an shared host and wrote an php shell for get piped emails. this host always make an error log like this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Suhosin Extension does not officially support PHP 5.2 and below anymore, because it is discontinued. Use it at your own risk. in Unknown on line 0
```

and this warning pass to mail delivery software and it think the mail didn't receive. I try to use **error_reporting(0)** and **ob_start()** with **ob_end_clean()**. but this error still pass to mail delivery software. how I can clear PHP startup warnings **with PHP codes in my script**?

Comment: you should probably just contact your hosting provider

Comment: Get a better hosting provider?

Comment: yes I know, but I'm writing an script that work on all hosts, and need to made it work properly on all kind of hosts. thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you try those options ? :
display_startup_errors & display_errors

Comment: how I can use these options? with ini_set()?

Comment: it is not work, I only can use ini_set and don't have permissions to php.ini, and this host don't accept custom php.ini

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini file look for "display_errors" and set it to Off. 
If you don't have access to the php.ini file, then at the START of your php file put:
ini_set("display_errors","Off");

Try this ..

Comment: Suhosin control configurations in php.ini and this error acure when its library load.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you get this startup error in php in the shell but not on normal web pages? If so, how are you piping the command through the shell? have you tried redirecting stderr to /dev/null ? -- i.e. append `2>/dev/null` to the command.

Alternative hackage could include piping through grep to filter out the line.

Comment: No, I get this error on all pages, but in normal pages it wrote on error_log files and not a big problem